# Asynchronously concatenating clicked numbers in a cleared string

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, asynchronous, concatenation

The goal of my small React experiment is "clear the initial value of `this.state.numString` (outputs an empty string), then concatenate the clicked numbers into `this.state.numString`". To make it execute asynchronously, I took advantage of `this.setState`'s callback where the concatenation of number strings happen.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    numString: '12'
  }

  displayAndConcatNumber = (e) => {
    const num = e.target.dataset.num;

    this.setState({
      numString: ''
    }, () => {
      this.setState({
        numString: this.state.numString.concat(num)
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const nums = Array(9).fill().map((item, index) => index + 1);
    const styles = {padding: '1rem 0', fontFamily: 'sans-serif', fontSize: '1.5rem'};

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {nums.map((num, i) => (
            <button key={i} data-num={num} onClick={this.displayAndConcatNumber}>{num}</button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div style={styles}>{this.state.numString}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The result was not what I expected; it only adds the current number I click into the empty string then change it into the one I click next, no concatenation of string numbers happens.

Comment: What's wrong with `this.setState({ numString: this.state.numString.concat(num) });`? Seems to work fine https://codesandbox.io/s/74725zy5p6

Comment: `setState` is already asynchronous. you're not making it any *more* asynchronous by using a callback, you're just performing another async operation after the next event loop

Comment: Also, in every `setState` you are resetting `numberString` to `""` again. Better to think of another logic.

Comment: @elclanrs It didn't clear the initial value of the state. It executes only the second `setState`

Comment: Why do you try to clear it when you overwrite it afterwards anyway?

Comment: @Bergi For the app that I'm currently developing

Comment: @Think-Twice It only does the concatenation, no clearing

Comment: @jstarnate this should be valid now this.setState({
    numString: ''
  }, () => {
    this.setState( prevState => ({
     numString: prevState.numString + num
    }));
  });

Comment: @Think-Twice, again, every time `numString` is being resetted with this code, too.

Comment: @devserkan isn’t that jstarnate expectation?

Comment: No. After first reset s/he wants to concatenate all the numbers (actually strings here). You can look at my working example.

Comment: Sorry about my late response. Adding another state really is the only solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below to clear the state immediately and concatenate the state with previous state value

```
this.setState({
    numString: ''
  }, () => {
    this.setState( prevState => ({
     numString: prevState.numString + num
    }));
  });
```

Comment: It should clear the initial value of `this.state.numString` first before concatenating the numbers

Comment: I never come across such situation before so didn't know much about it. I updated my answer now with your requirement. BTW because of your question I get to know the concept about how to make the state update immediately. Thanks

Comment: I think the only solution for that is adding another state

Answer (score 1):

The code above in your question , in first setState  you are setting variable to empty and in the second setState it is concatenating new value with empty string state. Thats why it is not working.

Try something like below:

```
   class App extends Component {
  state = {
  numString: '12',
  isFirstTime: true
  }

 displayAndConcatNumber = (e) =>  {
    const num =   e.target.dataset.num;
    if(this.state.isFirstTime){

      this.setState({
      numString: '',
      isFirstTime: false
    }, () => {
    this.setState({
    numString:     this.state.numString.concat(num)
     })
    })
    }else{
     this.setState({
     numString:    this.state.numString.concat(num)
  })
   }

 }

   render() {
    const nums =  Array(9).fill().map((item, index) => index + 1);
    const styles = {padding: '1rem 0', fontFamily: 'sans-serif', fontSize: '1.5rem'};

   return (
  <div>
    <div>
      {nums.map((num, i) => (
        <button key={i} data-  num={num} onClick={this.displayAndConcatNumber}>{num}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
    <div style={styles}>{this.state.numString}</div>
  </div>
);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thats representational

Comment: Edited the answer, try now @jstarnate

Comment: I just realized it's impossible if `numString` is the only state

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing this. As I said in my comment you are resetting the string in every `setState`. So, you need some kind of condition to do that.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    numString: '12',
    resetted: false,
  }

  displayAndConcatNumber = (e) => {
    const num = e.target.dataset.num;

    if ( !this.state.resetted ) {
      this.setState({
        numString: '',
        resetted: true,
      }, () => {
        this.setState( prevState => ({
         numString: prevState.numString.concat(num)
        }))
      })
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        numString: prevState.numString.concat(num)
      }))
    }
  }

  render() {
    const nums = Array(9).fill().map((item, index) => index + 1);
    const styles = { padding: '1rem 0', fontFamily: 'sans-serif', fontSize: '1.5rem' };

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {nums.map((num, i) => (
            <button key={i} data-num={num} onClick={this.displayAndConcatNumber}>{num}</button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div style={styles}>{this.state.numString}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I think adding another state is the only solution for the problem. But unlike your way, I added an array state that forms a string of numbers I type when used with `.join()` as the value for `this.state.numString` in the second `setState()`

Comment: Yes, there are various solutions to this problem.